# Is there any indication what rank is needed for powers that could destroy moons or planets?

Tags: marvel-faserip

Marvel has quite a few ranks that go to thors power level and beyond. I'm wondering though if there has ever been any indication what rank would be needed damagewise in order to destroy planets (as Galactus does).

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the Marvel Super Heroes game from 1984? That's what you tagged the question with, just want to make sure you didn't mean some related game.

Comment: @erik yepp that is the only one I've ever played   the 1984 game (the first one)

Answer (score 4):

Class 3000. But it is possible to use a Class 1000 attribute/rank power, and by pushing into Class 3000, to destroy a Planet.

In theory, if you are at Unearthly and Above, you have the theoretical power to target planets, As the Silver Surfer did, although its questionable whether you would get to skip some of the steps of Shift X, Y, and Z.

A Shift z (500) Could do it, going to 1000 and then 3000 with two steps up.

Class 3000 was the level for Celestials and Galactus, although Class 1000 was used for some other abilities. Class 1000 is also a default for Nuclear Attacks.

Universal Attacks are class 5000 and Beyonder. Death, Eternity, etc. Class 5000, Galactus High Evolutionary and Celestials Peak at Class 3000 and hurl planets. Class 1000 is wolverine's skeleton, nukes, and typical cosmic and reality bending characters at domestic, rather than intergalactic levels.

Comment: This anwer is a bit overly broad it seems, the question was specifically about that last one you mentioned. I would move that to the top, as the key part of the answer.

Comment: While they tagged marvel super heroes, i have no way of knowing that they just didn't type that without realizing that's a reference to a game out of print for over 30 years. So i listed them in order of publication.

Comment: I'll leave a comment for the OP, see if they clarify. I'd still put the one they tagged as primary though, just because of "assume good intentions". It IS what they tagged, for the time being.

Comment: I've got that game when it was still in print so yepp meant that one :) So meant the 1984 one.

Comment: What is interessting is the nukes part. Didn't know they ever statted them out.

Answer (score 0):

Anything beyond Unearthly could seriously damage a planet, depending on the plot. 
In comics, characters of really high power (Unearthly and above) will do such things depending on the story. Silver Surfer/ Firelord/ Thor destroying a planet is "acceptable" and "makes sense". While Hulk doing the same thing would not look right.

Mr Fantastic or Dr Doom, both of which are not uber-powered characters, could create device that might destroy the world (and IIRC did so more than once).

**So it depends on who is doing the destruction and how.**

Since you did not specify the situation, I assume that you are imagining a Galactus-like character showing up and destroying the earth. Anyone with a CL1000+ could do it in a simple swoop without people batting an eye.

Comment: Thor destroying a planet?  (btw you wrote plan)    wouldnt make sense to me though for thora

Comment: Both Thor and Beta Ray Bill (who has Thor's powers) destroyed planets at some time in the past. (https://comicvine.gamespot.com/thor/4005-2268/)